# Use Kirchhoff's laws to find the currents \$I_1\$ , \$I_2\$ and \$I_3\$

Tags: kirchhoffs-laws

I would like to find the currents  \$I_1\$ , \$I_2\$ and \$I_3\$.

[image]

I have the following equations for the currents between the branches \$AB\$ and \$CFB\$

\$I_{AB} = I_{CB} + I_{CFB}\$

\$I_{CFB} = I_1 - I_2 - I_3\$ based on \$I_1 = I_2 + I_3 + I_{CFB}\$

I have the following questions:

1. Is the current in the branch \$CFB\$ equal to \$I_1 - I_2 - I_3\$ (junction rule).
2. How does the current splits in node \$C\$ given the the node is between \$E_1\$ and \$E_2\$, and that they are connected oppositely?
3. Does the current in the branch \$AB\$ goes to the left?

Comment: If IAB means current flowing from A to B, then your first KCL equation is wrong. It should have been -IAB or IBA.

Comment: It would help greatly if you would mark the assumed direction of **all** currents on your diagram.

Comment: It would also help if we knew the value of **E**.